# Flask join children

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In my problem let's say there is Person which can have many Addresses and each Address can have one Location.

Is it possible to get a query where Persons contain Addresses which are joined with their Location?

```
class Person(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    addresses = db.relationship('Address', backref='person', lazy=True)

class Address(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    person_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('person.id'),
        nullable=False)
    location_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('location.id'))

class Location(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    location_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    address = relationship("Address", uselist=False, backref="location")
```

So when I loop persons I can access data from both Addresses and Location as one:

```
for person in persons:
    person.addresses.location_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
class Person(db.Model):
   def __init__(self):
       self.address = db.session.query( Address).filter( Address.person_id == self.id).first()

   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
   addresses = db.relationship('Address', backref='person', lazy=True)
```